# Example of a smooth function $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb S^n$ that does not extend to $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I am looking for examples of  *smooth* functions $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb S^n$  that do not extend to

1. a smooth function $\hat f:[0,1]\to \mathbb S^n$, and
2. a continuous function $\hat f:[0,1]\to \mathbb S^n$.

The reason is that I am interested in developing some intuition of cases when a map from a product of intervals cannot be extended.

**Some other cases I  worked out**

-If I had chosen a differet set of hypothesis, i.e. $f:C\subset I\to \mathbb S^n$ where $C$ is closed, then I could have used Tietze to conclude that $f$ could be extended to a continuous map over $I$. This is why I chose to take as a subset an open subset of $I$. However what about the derivatives?

-If $f$ is Lipschitz continous, (for example because somehow the derivatives are bounded) then I could use the theorem cited in  [Wikipedia under the Variation paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20topology%2C%20the%20Tietze%20extension,space%2C%20preserving%20boundedness%20if%20necessary.), so that $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb S^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ extends to a Lipschitz function
defined over $[0,1]$ taking values in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, by continuity however it would take values in $\mathbb S^n$.

Comment: Very basic comment: why not just make f spin around a "great circle" in Sn faster and faster as the parameter gets close to 1. are you looking for a closed form

Comment: @ChristianChapman Nice! Put it as an answer, I will upvote it. I hope to see more pathologies in other answers. If not I will accept it in a day or so.

Comment: Because such a function needs to fail to be Lipschitz and has a limit set which is a connected closed subset of $\mathbb S^n$, I guess all the examples will be similar to this one, with the "velocity" diverging as $t\to 1^-$. For example, you can manufacture one using the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).